# Transfer photos to iPod photo without iTunes?

Tags: software-rec, ipod, photos, file-transfer

I want to manage the photos on my iPod photo, but any iPod app I have tried will either not be able to transfer photos or corrupt the photos (they look posterized on the iPod).

Does anyone use an app that will do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [doubleTwist](http://www.doubletwist.com/dt/Home/Index.dt).  From their FAQ:

> doubleTwist is a free application for
>   Windows and Mac that helps you move
>   all your media onto all your devices;
>   i.e. sync your music, video and photo
>   libraries to your phone, MP3 player
>   and other moBile devices.